# Parse json response in Ansible and dynamically append new items to dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
- name: Create new instances
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

    new_instances:
      test_server1:
        datacenter: "paris"
        type: "A1"

      test_server2:
        datacenter: "london"
        type: "B1"

      test_server3:
        datacenter: "frankfurt"
        type: "C1"

  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve Openstack Flavor info
      openstack.cloud.compute_flavor_info:
        auth:
          auth_url: <secret>
          username: <secret>
          password: <secret>
          project_id: <secret>
        name: "{{ item.value.type }}"
        region_name: "{{ item.value.datacenter }}"
      with_dict: "{{ new_instances }}"
      register: flavor_output

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ flavor_output }}"
```

When running this play, I get a json response similar to the following:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "flavors": [
                    {
                        "description": null,
                        "disk": 50,
                        "ephemeral": 0,
                        "id": "DptkedSp2f3YhZmLTYLFBf3t",
                        "is_disabled": false,
                        "is_public": true,
                        "name": "A1",
                        "original_name": null,
                        "ram": 7000,
                        "rxtx_factor": 1.0,
                        "swap": "",
                        "vcpus": 2
                    }
                ],
                "item": {
                    "key": "test_server1",
                    "value": {
                        "datacenter": "paris",
                        "type": "A1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "flavors": [
                    {
                        "description": null,
                        "disk": 50,
                        "ephemeral": 0,
                        "id": "W2YcNHm9ZHMfzcP3T3WPjsmm",
                        "is_disabled": false,
                        "is_public": true,
                        "name": "B1",
                        "original_name": null,
                        "ram": 7000,
                        "rxtx_factor": 1.0,
                        "swap": "",
                        "vcpus": 2
                    }
                ],
                "item": {
                    "key": "test_server2",
                    "value": {
                        "datacenter": "london",
                        "type": "B1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "flavors": [
                    {
                        "description": null,
                        "disk": 100,
                        "ephemeral": 0,
                        "id": "drTdyFXRCKsxLy6kjJwKuZmR",
                        "is_disabled": false,
                        "is_public": true,
                        "name": "C1",
                        "original_name": null,
                        "ram": 15000,
                        "rxtx_factor": 1.0,
                        "swap": "",
                        "vcpus": 4
                    }
                ],
                "item": {
                    "key": "test_server3",
                    "value": {
                        "datacenter": "frankfurt",
                        "type": "C1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

The initial goal is to extract the flavor ID for each of the servers (or, more specifically, each datacenter).
Something like this partially works:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ flavor_output | json_query('results[*].flavors[*].id') }}"
```

But the filter returns all three IDs, without them being attributed to a specific server (and as much as I tried, I could not extract each individual ID per server). This is the current response:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "DptkedSp2f3YhZmLTYLFBf3t"
        ],
        [
            "W2YcNHm9ZHMfzcP3T3WPjsmm"
        ],
        [
            "drTdyFXRCKsxLy6kjJwKuZmR"
        ]
    ]
}
```

The final goal, what I actually want to achieve in the end, is to dynamically append the correct flavor ID for each server to the dictionary, so that it looks something like this:

```
   new_instances:
      test_server1:
        datacenter: "paris"
        type: "A1"
        flavor_id: "DptkedSp2f3YhZmLTYLFBf3t"

      test_server2:
        datacenter: "london"
        type: "B1"
        flavor_id: "W2YcNHm9ZHMfzcP3T3WPjsmm"

      test_server3:
        datacenter: "frankfurt"
        type: "C1"
        flavor_id: "drTdyFXRCKsxLy6kjJwKuZmR"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible is not able to *modify* the value of a variable (so you can't "dynamically append the correct flavor id for each server in the dictionary"), but you can *redefine* a variable with a new value.

You have all the information you need in your `flavor_output` variable; for each item in `flavor_output.results`; `item.item` contains the information from `new_instances` and `item.flavor` contains the result of the `compute_flavor_input` task.

We can write something like this:

```
- name: Retrieve Openstack Flavor info
  openstack.cloud.compute_flavor_info:
    name: "{{ item.value.type }}"
    region_name: "regionOne"
  with_dict: "{{ new_instances }}"
  register: flavor_output

- set_fact:
    new_instances: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for res in flavor_output.results %}
      {{
        {
          res.item.key: res.item.value | combine({'flavor_id': res.flavors[0].id})
        } | to_yaml
      }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

- debug:
    var: new_instances
```

I've modified the `type` values in your sample data to work with my environment; the `debug` task above produces this output:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_instances": {
        "test_server1": {
            "datacenter": "paris",
            "flavor_id": "15581358-3e81-4cf2-a5b8-c0fd2ad771b4",
            "type": "mem-a.8"
        },
        "test_server2": {
            "datacenter": "london",
            "flavor_id": "4498bfdb-5342-4e51-aa20-9ee74e522d59",
            "type": "mem-a.1"
        },
        "test_server3": {
            "datacenter": "frankfurt",
            "flavor_id": "2f33578f-c3df-4210-b369-84a998d77dac",
            "type": "mem-a.4"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works perfectly! I'm still having trouble understanding how the "new_instances" dictionary is being redefined with that jinja2 for loop. Based on what I'm seeing, I would've imagined that it would get overwritten completely. Will need to do a bit more research to understand how it works. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, by "redefined" I mean "overwritten completely". We are creating a *new* variable named `new_instances`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter [*json_query*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) to select the *[key, value]* pairs and the function [*dict*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-globals.dict) to create the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new_instances: "{{ dict(flavor_output.results|json_query(ni_query)) }}"
      vars:
        ni_query: '[].[item.key, merge(item.value, {flavor_id: flavors[0].id})]'
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  new_instances:
    test_server1:
      datacenter: paris
      flavor_id: DptkedSp2f3YhZmLTYLFBf3t
      type: A1
    test_server2:
      datacenter: london
      flavor_id: W2YcNHm9ZHMfzcP3T3WPjsmm
      type: B1
    test_server3:
      datacenter: frankfurt
      flavor_id: drTdyFXRCKsxLy6kjJwKuZmR
      type: C1
```

The attribute *flavors* is a list. In the above expression, only the first item is used. If you want to use all potential items from the list remove the index in the query

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new_instances: "{{ dict(flavor_output.results|json_query(ni_query)) }}"
      vars:
        ni_query: '[].[item.key, merge(item.value, {flavor_id: flavors[].id})]'
    - debug:
        var: new_instances
```

gives

```yaml
  new_instances:
    test_server1:
      datacenter: paris
      flavor_id: [DptkedSp2f3YhZmLTYLFBf3t]
      type: A1
    test_server2:
      datacenter: london
      flavor_id: [W2YcNHm9ZHMfzcP3T3WPjsmm]
      type: B1
    test_server3:
      datacenter: frankfurt
      flavor_id: [drTdyFXRCKsxLy6kjJwKuZmR]
      type: C1
```